# Optimize Android canvas background drawing by caching matrix

Tags: android, optimization, matrix, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a SurfaceView canvas I'm drawing a scene into.
The canvas is transformed to accomodate the logical scene size which is 1024x768 (while the actual screen is 800x480), and also to support zoom/scroll navigation on it.
Since I did not want black stripes on the sides (fitting 4:3 to 16:9) I'm using a different background bitmap which has "stretched" sides to cover the ratio difference.
Another twist in the plot, is that I need to support both phones and tables. For tablets I'm loading a higher quality (size) image and for phones I'm scaling down the background bitmap when loading it from disk.
Below is code that does what I want (although probably not the best way), and in particular, I have a feeling the background calculations can be cached into a matrix to be used later in `canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint);`

(Also, I couldn't get the equivalent positioning of drawBitmap(Bitmap, left, top, Paint) by translating the canvas with these offsets, I'm also curious why).

This is the draw routine:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {    
    canvas.save();
    float midX = width/2;
    float midY = height/2;

    // zoom out to fit logical view, and translate for future
    // sprite drawing with logical coordinates
    // x,y and zoom are calculated in on init and updated in touch events
    canvas.translate(x, y);
    canvas.scale(zoom, zoom, midX, midY);

    // background part
    if(back != null && !back.isRecycled()) {
        // todo: these can probably be pre-calculated for optimization
        // todo: but so far I couldn't get it right..
        if(bgMatrix != null) { // this is where I'm thinking of using the cached matrix
            canvas.drawBitmap(back, bgMatrix, paint);
        }
        else {
           float offsetW = (width-back.getWidth())/2;
           float offsetH = (height-back.getHeight())/2;

           canvas.save();
           // bgScaleFactor is calculated upon setting the bg bitmap
           // it says by how much we need to scale the image to fill the canvas
           // taking into account the image (possible) downscale 
           canvas.scale(bgScaleFactor, bgScaleFactor, midX, midY);
           // this doesn't work: canvas.postTranslate(offsetW, offsetH) and use 0,0 for next draw
           canvas.drawBitmap(back, offsetW, offsetH, paint);
           // todo: here I would like to save a matrix which represents
           // how the back bitmap was drawn onto the canvas
           // so that next time these calculations can be avoided
           // this fails: bgMatrix = canvas.getMatrix();
           canvas.restore();
    }

    // draw scene shapes on transformed canvas
    if(shapes != null){
    shapes.onDraw(canvas);
}

canvas.restore();
}
```